# Bluetooth Security Mode 2 - is there a regular pairing, as in Mode 1?

Tags: bluetooth

I read http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/drafts/800-121/sp800_121_r2_draft.pdf and https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439. but I can not find there information about Bluetooth Security Mode 2.

I know that:

- Low energy Security Mode 2 has multiple levels associated with data signing. Data signing provides strong data integrity but not confidentiality.
- Level 1 requires unauthenticated pairing with data signing. Level 2 requires authenticated pairing with data signing.

But there should be some pairing first, before data signing can be used, right? The problem is, if the pairing looks like in Mode 1, or its a different procedure?

Answer (score 1):

> But there should be some pairing first, before data signing can be
>   used, right?

The initial pairing is completed on the physical layer (You have to press the button on the Bluetooth device) before the handshake/protocol is initiated. Your next question is:

> The problem is, if the pairing looks like in Mode 1, or its a
>   different procedure?

The answer is No. The pairing is the same. Regardless of the Security mode, encryption mode, or service level. The initial pairing/setup starts with a button press (or some other physical interaction between authorized parties/ owners and the Bluetooth devices).

[Source](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj_8K6nkNHRAhWEKCYKHY_BAxcQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.jabra.com%2F~%2Fmedia%2FDocumentation%2FWhitepapers%2FWP_Bluetooth_50004_V01_1204.ashx&usg=AFQjCNHnxLvUOaFYNgBkRkAn9Tq6a6qx3w)

[Source](http://www.ece.umd.edu/class/ents650/BluetoothSecurity.pdf)